# How to add label to a scene? (SceneKit)

Tags: swift, xcode, label, scenekit

I want to add a label and a button to my scene. I am using SceneKit framework. I created a label and button but somehow my button is working but my label is not appearing.

What should I do?

Here is my code;

```
func createSCNView(scene: SCNScene) {
    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    
    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene
    
    // add a button to the scene
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.black
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 25)
    button.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressBack), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.center.x = 50
    button.frame.origin.y = 20
    scnView.addSubview(button)

    let expLabel = UILabel()
    expLabel.text = "Lütfen geliştirmek istediğiniz kas grubunu seçiniz"
    expLabel.textColor = .black
    expLabel.textAlignment = .center
    expLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    expLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    expLabel.frame = .init(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.height - 60, width: 100, height: 25)
    expLabel.sizeToFit()
    expLabel.isEnabled = false
    scnView.addSubview(expLabel)
    
    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    
    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = false
    
    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your view’s frame is set at this point? My guess is your label is -60px off the top.